# Robert Boyle's discovery of electricity

Tags: electricity, experimental-physics, history

I want to know what is the contribution of Robert Boyle in this discovery of electricity after Otto von gueriche?

Comment: You probably should ask this on the [History of Science & Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Or do some research - text books etc may well cover this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert Boyle does the same experiment on electricity that is taking a body and rubbing it to make it a charged body and seeing attraction of light object.He concludes that electric phenomena only shows attraction and not repulsion like the magnet which shows both attraction and repulsion